# php mysql show result one after another

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna build a presence check for our choir in the style of tinder but not as complex.

The database contains names and file paths of pictures of the members. When you click on the "present" or "not present" button, the next picture and name should be shown. In the background, the database table should be updated with true/false for presence. (this will be done later)

My problem is that it almost works, but instead of showing one member, it shows all members with their pictures in one single page.

I understand that I could fire with Javascript to continue and paused php-function but I don't get the clue how.

I tried "break" in the php and call the function again but that didn't work.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli(myServer, myUser, myPass, myDbName);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mitglieder";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<img class='pic' src='" .$row["folder"]. "/" .$row["img"]. "'><br>" ;
    echo "<div id='name'>" .$row["vorname"]. " " .$row["name"]. "</div>    <br>";
    echo "<img src=''img.png' id='present' onclick='isPresent()'>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
<html>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log("Ready");
);
</html>`
```

Comment: What you're looking for is usually called "pagination" and the LIMIT clause.

Comment: You'll have to update your query to show one member `LIMIT 1` at a time and add a where clause that checks if they are in attendance `WHERE attendance = x`

Comment: Do you have a web page with Javascript that calls this PHP code on a server and, if so, does it use XHR type requests or a simple submit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function

> mysqli_fetch_all()

assign it on the variable outside the while loop and loop or access the indexes in your code.

For Example:

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all();
echo $data[0]['name'];
foreach($data as $item)
{
  echo $item['name'];
}
```

Comment: This is no different than the OP's attempt, it will still return all the rows and that function is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to establish a "state" between your web page and the PHP backend so that you can step through the data. I suggest something like this:

Use an auto-increment integer primary key for the database. That way you can access the data in index order. Let's name the column `id`

Have your JS code send a form variable - named something like `LAST_ID` to the PHP in your get. i.e `http://someurl.com/script.php?LAST_ID=0`

On your first call to the server, send LAST_ID = 0

In your PHP code, fetch the value like this: $id = $_GET('LAST_ID');

Change your SQL query to use the value to fetch the next member like this:
`$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM mitglieder where id > %d limit 1", $id);` That will get the next member from the DB and return only 1 row (or nothing at the end of data).

Make sure to return the id as part of the form data back to the page and then set LAST_ID to that value on the next call.

You can use a HTTP POST with a form variable to the server call that sets that member id to present (maybe a different script or added to your same PHP script with a test for POST vs GET). I suggest a child table for that indexed on id and date.

I hope that puts you in a good direction. Good luck